# pdf Export Timeout issue -ssrs 2014

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, msbi, ssrs-2014

The Reports which have less than 5 MB size, it is downloading fine.When the size exceeds 5MB, it through below error.

**The operation has timed out.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out.**

Answer (score 0):

Set Timeout to 10 mins in your .Net code. Default its 5 mins. I hope this works for you!